# Null data column returns input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, exception, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an event calendar in which time values (start, end) are not always required and are often `Null`. I'd like the format for times that *are* entered to read `hh:mm tt`. I have the code check for null values using the following `if` statement:

```
<td>
    @If item.StartTime IsNot Nothing Then
        @item.StartTime.ToString("h:mm tt")
    Else
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.StartTime)
    End If
</td>
```

I *still* get the following error espite the `if` statement:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +224
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +92

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "h:mm tt" to type 'Integer' is not valid.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +248
ASP._Page_Views_EaglesEvents_Index_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\Users\Iluvw\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MVC Projects\Eagles3555\Eagles3555\Views\EaglesEvents\Index.vbhtml:49
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +73
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<InvokeEndHandler>b__0() +32
System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +107
System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +23
Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) +64
System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +56
System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +91
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +123
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +128
```

The line highlighted in red is `@item.StartTime.ToString("h:mm tt")`. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** My model code for the time fields:

```
<Display(Name:="Date")>
<DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True)>
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
Public Property EventDate As DateTime
<Display(Name:="Start Time")>
<DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:hh:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True)>
<DataType(DataType.Time)>
Public Property StartTime As DateTime?
```

Comment: You should just be able to assign a DisplayFormat attribute to the StartTime property:  `<DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:= "{0:h:mm tt}")>` then remove the null check and just put the @Html.Display element in for it.

Comment: I already used `<DisplayFormat>` to make sure the existing data, if any, was shown on the Edit page and not lost. Great idea, though! Thanks. :D

Comment: The issue appears to be not the value of `StartTime` but the data type. What is that data type? You appear to be assuming that it is `Date`/`DateTime` but the error message indicates that, whatever it is, it has no `ToString` overload that has a `String` parameter. The error message indicates that that code is actually being interpreted as `item.StartTime.ToString().Chars("h:mm tt")`, where `Chars` requires a numeric index and you're providing a `String`. The very first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On`, which would catch issues like this at compile time.

Comment: The data type is `DateTime`. I turned Strict on in Web.config and ran the site again. The InnerException remains the same, but it is also says `InvalicCastException: 'Conversion from string "h:mm tt" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you are using a Nullable DateTime which does not have a `ToString()` method that accepts a format string.  If you are first doing a null check then you can address this by performing the `ToString()` on the `Value` of the Nullable which will be the DateTime:

```
@If item.StartTime IsNot Nothing Then
        @item.StartTime.Value.ToString("h:mm tt")
// ...
```